# system("chcp 1251"); не работает

Tags: c, кодировка

По какой то причине команда system("chcp 1251"); не работает так как надо. Вместо кириллического текста командная строка выдаёт: РЇР·С‹Рє РЎ: РїРµСЂРІР°СЏ РїСЂРѕРіСЂР°РјРјР°. При этом при удалении команды system("chcp 1251");. то же ничего не меняется

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    system("chcp 1251");

    printf("Язык С: первая программа");

    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ключевое слово: utf-8.

Comment: Как я понял по умолчанию в виндоус стоит кодировка utf-8. Я её пытаюсь поменять в поле работы програаммы командой указаной выше. И она не меняется. В этом проблема

Comment: Обычно по умолчанию в консоли Windows кодировка 866. А в исходнике - utf-8.